# HTMLform IDP adaptor log-out

Tags: pingfederate

How HTMLform IDP adaptor log-out is working in pingfederate? It seems not specific to any service providers configurations(no need to configure logout service url in SP) and its terminate all the service provider session associated with user.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SLO in PingFederate works the same way, regardless of the authentication mechanism used (authentication adapter).

When starting SLO, the browser presents the PF session token to the server. The server finds all SSO sessions associated with that PF session, and then sends a LogoutRequest to every SP, in a serial fashion. As long as a response comes back from the SP indicating a successful logout, the process continues to loop through other providers. When all sessions have been closed PingFed destroys the PF session, and sends the browser to a location as specified in the adapter.

Please note that a successful SLO depends on the SPs' willingness to respond in a SAML-compliant manner.